# Add file object to an array in file upload

Tags: angular, file-upload

Want to send file object in array item along with other field. I am trying to achieve structure given in image,

please let me know if
any suggestion.

[upload multiple file structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC9VF.png)

the component is like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3hwcmv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I selectAttachment() function,  I am trying to put the **file object**  in array element along with price.

I want to send the entire attachmentArray to back-end along with fileobject for each row whose file is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you get the `FileList` in your property `attachmentArray`

```
  selectAttachment(event, i) {
    const file: File = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const fileName = file.name;
      this.attachmentArray[i].fileName = fileName;
      this.attachmentArray[i].file = file;
    }
    console.log(event.target);
    console.log(this.attachmentArray); 
  }
```

When tried logging from `uploadFile`, it logs the sample object on actual browser console[image: Actual browser console]
[image: Upload full log]
[image: uploadFile res on stackblitz console]